# How to handle error STDERR in chef

Tags: error-handling, chef-infra

How we can handle chef error during convergence stage. I'm inspecting to tackle error during package resource run and on getting that exception/error it would notify other resource to execute.

I understand this we can tackle with handlers but how to write handler module to execute code only if certain kind of stderr is encountered or exception is occurred.

e.g.

---

```
3: package "mdadm" do
4:   timeout '300'
5: end
6:


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: package[mdadm] (cookbook-common::raid line 3) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides --yum-lock-timeout 30 ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: Fatal Python error: pycurl: libcurl link-time version is older than compile-time version
```

---

---

Comment: Don't try to fix if you find an error, describe the desired state of the system. If you need specific tasks to be done, do them before installing this package...

Answer (score 2):

Chef is a convergent system built around promise theory. There is no specific handling for errors because each unit of promise (generally resources in Chef) is expected to be internally idempotent and handle this kind of thing itself. If a resource is forced to error, it is presumed to be globally fatal.